# Android MapActivity - Grid

Tags: android, apk, mapactivity

I have a developed app with a `MapActivity`. The app works great when I install it via USB to my phone, but I've exported the **APK** to some others and they only get the grid.

What causes this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using a full release Maps key.

Comment: Thanks. I just made a public one and exported the APK. But now when I try to use the jarsigner tool, I get "jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for res/layout/balloon_overlay.xml"

Comment: Cleaning the project and re-exporting fixed the problem.